# How can I create dynamic conditionals in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to create a script to go through the files of a specific folder and then move the files based on criteria to specific folders.I can write it with the criteria I want, but I would like if I wanted to change a criteria not to change the actual script, rather change a text file.

A sample code:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

while True:
   files = [item for item in listdir(target_folder) if isfile(join(target_folder,item ))]
   for each_file in files:
       if each_file.endswith('.exe'):
           print 'File Found.
```

What I really want to do is an alternative of Belvedere http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc .I have created the gui for the most part, but I am not clear on the rest of the necessary code.I tried to read the Belvedere source, but I got confused.

Comment: you want to change contents of the file or change the criteria to select those files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what you mean, but you could define a single-argument function on your if statement and then change that later on if you needed to, i.e.:

```
from os import listdir,
from os.path import isfile, join

def matching_file(path):
    return path.endswith(".exe")

while True:
    files = [item for item in listdir(target_folder) if isfile(join(target_folder, item))]
    for each_file in files:
        if matching_file(each_file):
            print "File found."
        if "PYTHON" in each_file:
            matching_file = lambda x: x.endswith(".py")
```

this is just a silly example, but you could substitute in anything for `matching_file` and thus be able to change your criteria on the fly.